# What's the meaning of the raised finger in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Prior to Iron Man's

> final moments,

he sees Strange raise his index finger. I presume this is some kind of message, but I didn't understand the meaning. It seems Stark immediately knows what to do - i.e.

> steal the Stones using his nano-tech.

Comment: I take it as "This is the moment"

Comment: so it doesn't have any specific importance to stark's actions afterwards?

Comment: Strange is telling Stark that this is indeed the one possible future where they win. He's reassuring Stark that the sacrifice he's about to make will be successful.